Using Excel VBA to run OpenSSL in several cells
I need to encrypt all the cells of a single column with OpenSSL. I've done it recently writing in a PIN.txt file the cell value and running the command from Windows CMD:
openssl rsautl -encrypt -in PIN.txt -out PIN.enc -inkey certificateXX.cer - certin -pkcs

How can I do for all the column cells?
Better explanation:
I'd need to:

pick the A2 cell text

export in an A2.txt file

run cmd:
openssl rsautl -encrypt -in PIN.txt -out PIN.enc -inkey certificateXX.cer - certin -pkcs

copy the content of generated A2.enc file in cell B2


and so on, up to cell A100
Thanks
tried to run it manually to cmd, but it's too much work for more than 100 cells
